# Display a post by ID attribute with shortcode

Tags: posts, shortcode

I'm trying to create a shortcode that displays a banner containing a post content (thumbnail, title and excerpt), using ID attribute. My goal is to be able to use a shortcode like `[postbanner id=123]` to display any post by its ID.

Here is my code (in function.php child theme):

```
function post_banner_shortcode($atts) {
    
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => ''
    ), $atts );
    
    $post_id = $atts['id'];
    
    $HTML  = '<div class="postbanner">';
    $HTML .= '<div class="pb-thumb">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'medium') . '</div>';
    $HTML .= '<div class="pb-ttl-txt">';
    $HTML .= '<h4>' . get_the_title($post_id) . '</h4>';
    $HTML .= '<p>' . get_the_excerpt($post_id) . '</p>';
    $HTML .= '</div>';
    $HTML .= '</div>';
    
    return $html; 
}   
add_shortcode( 'postbanner', 'post_banner_shortcode' );
```

Actually this code return nothing and I don't understant why. I'm missing something here. I'm still a *rookie* with PHP so that's why I need some help guys :)

Comment: Did you try to debug $atts inside the function - for example ```var_dump( $atts );``` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$HTML` instead of `$html` Linux based systems are case-sensitive ...

```php
function post_banner_shortcode($atts) {
    
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => ''
    ), $atts );
    
    $post_id = $atts['id'];
    
    $HTML  = '<div class="postbanner">';
    $HTML .= '<div class="pb-thumb">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'medium') . '</div>';
    $HTML .= '<div class="pb-ttl-txt">';
    $HTML .= '<h4>' . get_the_title($post_id) . '</h4>';
    $HTML .= '<p>' . get_the_excerpt($post_id) . '</p>';
    $HTML .= '</div>';
    $HTML .= '</div>';
    
    return $HTML; 
}   
add_shortcode( 'postbanner', 'post_banner_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Once again, it's obvious but I didn't saw it lol. Thanks a lot Q Studio

Comment: Better to stick to lowercase or camelCase - if there are multiple words in the variable name - $for_example or $forExample

Comment: I didn't bother to scroll down and check if there was an answer and at first glance I thought "this looks correct"... ...so I copied it into my text editor and went line by line and found the `$HTML`/`$html` differentiation as well... ...LOL!  I really need to check if there's an answer before I start parsing through code.

Comment: My eyes skipped it too, not expected.. but something smelt wrong ;)